# How to increase size of OpenLDAP MDB database? (MDB_MAP_FULL Error Code)

Tags: ubuntu, ldap, openldap, slapd

I'm getting this error related to slapd service (OpenLDAP server) in syslog

> mdb_idl_insert_keys: c_put id failed: MDB_MAP_FULL: Environment
>   mapsize limit reached (-30792)

This error comes when I'm trying to add new users on OpenLDAP, I'm using MDB database and After searching for cause of this error I came to know my MDB database size if full and I need to increase the maxsize of database but how I do that? I'm using cn=config style configuration and my OpenLDAP version is 2.44.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out I need to change value of **olcDbMaxSize** attribute in my database configuration file.

I tried below and it worked.

**Step 1: Create ldif file(filename.ldif) with below contents**

```
dn: olcDatabase={2}mdb,cn=config
changetype: modify
add: olcDbMaxSize
olcDbMaxSize: 1000000000
```

> Note : olcDbMaxSize : size in bytes

**Step 2: Import above ldif file to OpenLDAP**

```
ldapmodify -x -W -D 'cn=config' -H ldap:// -f filename.ldif
```

**Step 3:Restart slapd service** (This may not be required in cn=config style configuration)

```
service slapd restart
```